# how to replicate ExternalFileField file on SolrCloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have the External File Field configured and working on a non-cloud Solr setup. Now I need to apply the same to a SolrCloud setup. I have 3 shard and 3 replication factors. 
The EFF file needs to go into the data directory of the solr index. How do I upload/update the EFF file, since I have about 3 shards on 3 solr servers each.

Can Zookeeper be used to maintain these files too?

The issue is that updating these files manually, means going to each shard/replica and update them manually.

Any guidance anyone could provide about EFF and SolrCloud.

Thanks,
Brijesh